# Why does my RewriteLog not work?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, .htaccess, mac, mamp

I have an .htaccess which looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteLog "/Applications/MAMP/logs/rewrite_engine_log"

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/(index.php|css|images|js)/.*$
RewriteRule (.*) /mysite/index.php/$1
```

When I add that RewriteLog directive, I get an Internal Server Error.

In the Apache log files I get this info:

```
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysite/.htaccess: RewriteLog not allowed here
```

I did not create that rewrite_engine_log file manually, but that path /Applications/MAMP/logs/ exists on my mac. What can I try next to get RewriteEngine logfiles?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It pretty much means what it says.  You can't put a RewriteLog directive in an .htaccess file.  If you need it, your only option is to put it in the server config or in a virtual host's config section:

[apache's mod_rewrite man page](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog)

Comment: where's that server config?

Comment: I'm not on a mac, but I think it's located at 

/Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/httpd.conf